# Can't recreate popup window after theme is changed - Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have an android app with a feature to change its theme using settings. I have a popup window on my screen (with radio button for light and dark theme) and it works perfectly!
But the problem is that when I change my theme the popup window dissapears and this error is thrown:

```
E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.rempaudioeditor.SettingsActivity has leaked window android.widget.PopupWindow$PopupDecorView{e82989b V.E...... .......D 0,0-788,534} that was originally added here
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:485)
        at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:346)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:93)
        at android.widget.PopupWindow.invokePopup(PopupWindow.java:1433)
        at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAtLocation(PopupWindow.java:1203)
        at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAtLocation(PopupWindow.java:1170)
        at com.example.rempaudioeditor.dispatch.DispatchPopup.sendPopupAtCenter(DispatchPopup.java:19)
        at com.example.rempaudioeditor.SettingsActivity.onSettingsItemClick(SettingsActivity.java:57)
        at com.example.rempaudioeditor.arrayadapters.SettingsItemsAdapter$ViewHolder.onClick(SettingsItemsAdapter.java:68)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa2b85120: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa2b832e0)
D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0x92968b80 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xa2b83e50
I/zygote: Do full code cache collection, code=70KB, data=73KB
I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=47KB, data=34KB
E/ViewRootImpl[PopupWindow:f7e7f78]: Could not lock surface
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at android.view.Surface.nativeLockCanvas(Native Method)
        at android.view.Surface.lockCanvas(Surface.java:318)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.drawSoftware(ViewRootImpl.java:3045)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:3019)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2806)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2359)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1392)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6752)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

I think my popup window is not being recreated properly but how do I fix this?

Comment: Before changing theme close the popup then after changed create popup again...

Comment: @GobuCSG The popup window is not getting dismissed even after calling `popup.dismiss()` just before the theme change. I am still getting the error. Am I dissmissing it the wrong way?